# Struct with an array returns random value

Tags: arduino, arduino-esp8266, arduino-c++

Recently I got my hands on NodeMCU esp8266. I am trying to build an alarm system. I have two structs Alarm and AlarmInfo. What I'm trying to do is read the data from the File system, parse it and use it to determine the active preset (AlarmInfo). Each Preset can have multiple alarms and I use an array of alarms. I don't know what am I doing wrong. When I tried to run the same code in dev-c++ (with some changes to the output) it worked. Here is the code:

```
#include <FS.h>
#include <LittleFS.h>


#include "AsyncJson.h"
#include "ArduinoJson.h"

//Alarm Struct
struct Alarm {
  private:
    int alarmHour;// 00 - 23;
    int alarmMinute; // 00 - 59;
    int duration; //undefined
  public:
    Alarm(int newAlarmHour, int newAlarmMinute, int newDuration) {
      alarmHour = newAlarmHour;
      alarmMinute = newAlarmMinute;
      duration = newDuration;
    }
    Alarm() {}
    int getAlarmHour() {
      return alarmHour;
    }
    int getAlarmMinute() {
      return alarmMinute;
    }
    int getAlarmDuration() {
      return duration;
    }
    String toString() { // returns string representation only of the alarm (format: hh:mm)
      char buffer[10];
      sprintf(buffer, "%02u:%02u", alarmHour, alarmMinute);
      return String(buffer);
    }
    String toStringDuration() { // returns string representation with duration (format: hh:mm/dd)
      char buffer[20];
      sprintf(buffer, "%02u:%02u:%d", alarmHour, alarmMinute, duration);
      return String(buffer);
    }
};

struct AlarmInfo {
  private:
    String name;
    Alarm *alarms;
    int alarmSize;
    int *days;
    int daySize;
    boolean isActive;
  public:
    AlarmInfo() {}
    AlarmInfo(String newName, Alarm newAlarms[], int newAlarmSize, int newDays[], int newDaySize, boolean newIsActive) {
      name = newName;
      alarms = newAlarms;
      alarmSize = newAlarmSize;
      days = newDays;
      daySize = newDaySize;
      isActive = newIsActive;
    }
    Alarm* getAlarms() {
      return alarms;
    };
    void readVals() {
      Alarm *temp = alarms;
      Serial.print("Size: ");
      Serial.println(alarmSize);
      for (int i = 0; i < alarmSize; i++) {
        Serial.println(temp++->toStringDuration());
      }
    }
};


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("Hello There");
  
  LittleFS.begin();
  File file = LittleFS.open("/presetdata.json", "r");
  if(!file) {
    Serial.println("Cannot read the file");
  }
  DynamicJsonDocument data(8192);
  deserializeJson(data, file);
  loadAlarms(data.as<JsonArray>());

}

void loop() {
}


void loadAlarms(JsonArray jsonArray) {
  AlarmInfo alarmInfos[jsonArray.size()];
  ////////////////////////Parsing JSON////////////////////////////////
  for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.size(); i++) {
    JsonObject object = jsonArray[i].as<JsonObject>();
    String alarmInfoName = object["Name"].as<String>();
    JsonArray alarmsJsonArray = object["Alarms"].as<JsonArray>();
    Alarm alarmArray[alarmsJsonArray.size()];
    for (int j = 0; j < alarmsJsonArray.size(); j++) {
      JsonObject alarmObject = alarmsJsonArray[j].as<JsonObject>();
      int alarmHour = alarmObject["hour"];
      int alarmMinute = alarmObject["minute"];
      int duration = alarmObject["duration"];

      alarmArray[j] = Alarm(alarmHour, alarmMinute, duration);
    }
    JsonArray daysJsonArray = object["Days"].as<JsonArray>();
    int daysArray[daysJsonArray.size()];
    for (int k = 0; k < daysJsonArray.size(); k++) {
      daysArray[k] = daysJsonArray[k].as<int>();
    }
    bool isActive = object["Active"].as<bool>();
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    alarmInfos[i] = AlarmInfo(alarmInfoName, alarmArray, alarmsJsonArray.size(),
                              daysArray, daysJsonArray.size(), isActive);
    alarmInfos[i].readVals();
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.size(); i++) {
    alarmInfos[i].readVals();
  }
}
```

This is the output:

```
Size: 6
12:30:5
13:30:5
14:30:5
15:30:5
16:30:5
17:30:5
Size: 6
17:30:5
17:30:5
18:30:5
19:30:5
20:30:5
21:30:5
Size: 6
17:30:5
17:30:5
18:30:5
19:30:5
20:30:5
21:30:5
Size: 6
17:30:5
17:30:5
18:30:5
19:30:5
20:30:5
21:30:5
Size: 6
17:1073672900:107373
1075862441:825898801
943337780:959984946:
00:1310751:0
20:30:5
1073736416:06:0
Size: 6
17:1073672900:107373
1075862441:825898801
943337780:959984946:
00:1310751:0
20:30:5
1073736416:06:0
Size: 6
17:1073672900:107373
1075862441:825898801
943337780:959984946:
00:1310751:0
20:30:5
1073736416:06:0
Size: 6
17:1073672900:107373
1075862441:825898801
943337780:959984946:
00:1310751:0
20:30:5
1073736416:06:0
```

Comment: You should learn how to write a constructor. E.g. what a initializer list is. Overwrite already set parms in the constructor is typically not what you want to do! And havin default constructors which do no initialization... seems wrong to me.

Comment: I failed to find the question in your post, what do you need?

Comment: @Klaus can you help me with the initializer list since I cannot understand it?

Comment: @pptaszni It's more like a problem I get random values when trying to read my AlarmInfo from the array.

Comment: Probably out of range access, or similar. Just use `std::vector` instead of raw arrays (e.g. this code `Alarm alarmArray[alarmsJsonArray.size()];` is not valid C++), use `std::vector::at` instead of `operator[]`, then if there is still some problem, reduce the code to smaller example and then debug. As for the constructors: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor

Comment: You have to copy the arrays in the AlarmInfo constructor.

Comment: If one default constructs an `Alarm` and then calls `getAlarmHour()` you have UB by way of reading an initialized variable (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). And that's just one of many issues.

Comment: Write small amount of code and debug often. Learn to use a debugger.

Comment: ESP8266 (and ESP32) supports `Serial.printf()` out of the box, your `toString()` and `toStringConfiguration()` isn't necessary, you can simply call `Serial.printf(""%02u:%02u:%d", alarmHour, alarmMinute, duration);`.

Comment: Use [ctime](https://cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/), and save time as string in your file system with `strftime()`, and retrieve it and convert it to a `struct tm`, no need to re-invent the wheel and your code will be at least 2/3 shorter and easier to read. Sometime json format is not the best way for such application.

Answer (score 0):

In `loadAlarms`, `alarmArray` and `daysArray` goes out of scope at the end of each iteration of the for loop. For a quick solution, you can use dynamic allocation:

```
Alarm* alarmArray = new Alarm[alarmsJsonArray.size()];
```

Of course then you have to take care of the deallocation.

It would be best to use a `std::vector` like class.